# Prove that maximum 9 trailing zeroes in this summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am trying to prove that there are a maximum of 9 trailing $0$'s at the end of this summation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{k=m} k^n$$
for  $1\le n\le 1000000$ and $m\le 100$.

Any help on how to approach?

Comment: there is no limit for m, i suppose... Because, if there isn't, n=1 and m=20000000000 will have 10 zeros.

Comment: @jonnytan999. The OP wrote $1 \leq n \leq 1000000$.

Comment: i am asking about m

Comment: @jonnytan999. I am sorry ! I did misread !!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, question updated.

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Comment: http://acm.zju.edu.cn/onlinejudge/showProblem.do?problemCode=3549

Comment: Are you sure you'll have 9 trailing zeros (and not less)?

Comment: @tpb261 'Maximum' 9 trailing zeros.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar Yes I get that, but when I try I'm not even able to get to two zeros, so I thought maybe you had some example for the case of 9 zeros. What is that, the first digit of the powers of digits repeats for every 4 values. For eg. for 3, the last digit would be: 3,9,7,1,3,9....